# How can I return my desired array of results

Tags: ruby

I have a code that is not giving the desired return. Below is the code

```
class Turn
  def initialize(passcode:)
    @passcode = passcode
  end

  def guess(colors)
    result = []
    passcode.each_with_index do |passcode_color, idx|
      if colors[idx] == passcode_color
        result << :exact
      elsif colors.include?(passcode_color)
        result << :partial
      end
    end
    result
  end

  private

  attr_reader :passcode
end

passcode = ["RED", "GREEN", "BLUE", "YELLOW"]

player = Turn.new(passcode: passcode)

player.guess(["RED", "GREEN", "BLUE", "GREEN"]
```

The above method call gave this output => [:exact,:exact, :exact].

Meanwhile this is my desired output => [:exact,:exact, :exact, :partial].

I think the last color (GREEN) in the colors array is included in the passcode but not at the exact position, hence expecting partial.

Please, how can I modify the code to get this output => [:exact,:exact, :exact, :partial].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `"YELLOW"` isn't in `colors` so nothing is added to your `result` for that eventuality.

You may instead wish to use `#map`. Using the following, in the `"YELLOW"` case, `nil` will be added the resulting array.

```
class Turn
  def initialize(passcode:)
    @passcode = passcode
  end

  def guess(colors)
    @passcode.each_with_index.map do |passcode_color, idx|
      if colors[idx] == passcode_color
        :exact
      elsif colors.include? passcode_color
        :partial
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If you want to include something like `:notfound` for that scenario, you could add an `else`.

```
class Turn
  def initialize(passcode:)
    @passcode = passcode
  end

  def guess(colors)
    @passcode.each_with_index.map do |passcode_color, idx|
      if colors[idx] == passcode_color
        :exact
      elsif colors.include? passcode_color
        :partial
      else
        :notfound
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback. You are right that YELLOW is omitted, hence return nil. As for the GREEN color, it is both present at the exact position and wrong position. I want the one at the wrong position to return partial so that the final output will be [:exact, :exact, :exact, :partial]. I tried your suggested code, but it did not work.

Comment: You are iterating over the `passcode` array, though, not `colors`. The first three `"RED"`, `"GREEN"` and `"BLUE"` _are_ exact matches for the `colors` array. When it gets to `"YELLOW"` it neither finds an exact nor a partial match.

Comment: You'd want to swap `@passcode` and `colors` in the `#guess` method.

Comment: Do you suggest I iterate over the colors instead of the passcode?

Comment: Okay, let me try that.

Comment: It sounds like that's what you want to do, and it would produce the result you're looking for.